# Como fazer consulta envolvendo mais de uma tabela (JPA) utilizando JPQL

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

Olá, tenho uma consulta utilizando SQL, agora estou alterando o projeto utilizando JPA e gostaria de alterar as consultas de forma coerente com o JPA.

```
    public void gerarConsulta() {

    jTResultado.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(50);
    jTResultado.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(100);
    jTResultado.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(100);
    jTResultado.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(100);
    jTResultado.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(100);
    jTResultado.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(100);
    jTResultado.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(100);
    DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) jTResultado.getModel();
    modelo.setNumRows(0);

    Statement st;

    try {
        st = con.createStatement();
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from funcionario_ocorrencia " + ""
                + "inner join funcionario on funcionario.funcionario_id = funcionario_ocorrencia.funcionario_id "
                + "inner join setor    on setor.setor_id      = funcionario.setor_id "
                + "inner join ocorrencia    on ocorrencia.ocorrencia_id       = funcionario_ocorrencia.ocorrencia_id   "
                + "inner join empresa    on empresa.empresa_id      = funcionario.empresa_id "
                + "where funcionario_ocorrencia.ocorrencia_data_pg between '" + jFormatDataInicial.getText() + "'" + "and '" + jFormatDataFinal.getText() + "'"
                + " and funcionario.funcionario_id = '" + jTMatricula.getText() + "'");

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("funcionario_id");
            String nome = rs.getString("funcionario_descr");
            String empresa = rs.getString("empresa_descr");
            String setor = rs.getString("setor_descr");
            String ocorrenciaTipo = rs.getString("ocorrencia_descr");
            double ocorrencia_valor = rs.getDouble("ocorrencia_valor");
            String data = rs.getString("ocorrencia_data_pg");
            modelo.addRow(new Object[]{id, nome, empresa, setor, ocorrenciaTipo, ocorrencia_valor, data});
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Problemas ao tentar conectar com o banco de dados");
    }

}
```

Li alguns posts, alguns exemplos, mas está confuso, pois apenas havia feito da forma que está neste código, creio que ficará deselegante, visto que estou alterando este pequeno projeto para a especificação JPA.Se alguém puder ajudar, sou grato.

Comment: Dúvidas: seu código dá algum erro ou resultado inesperado? O que considera "deselegante"? Por favor, clique em [edit] e esclareça diretamente na pergunta.

Comment: Nao dá erro, desta forma funciona corretamente, utilizando SQL . Gostaria de utilizar algo como JPQL, por exemplo, foi isso que quis dizer com "coerente com JPA e que acredito que JDBC com JPA ficaria deselegante", não sei se ficou mais claro o que quis dizer.